# How to create a loop by matching variables

Tags: jquery, arrays, image, loops, attributes

I am looking to loop through 2 separate arrays to match up attributes. Instead of writing a line of code for each image in my array, it would be nice to say, "Grab all of the images and duplicate them into another array."

```
var arr = new Array();
$('.single-project .et_pb_slide_image img').each(function(){
     arr.push($(this).attr('src'));
});

var arr2 = new Array();
$('.single-project .et-pb-controllers a img').each(function() {
     arr2.push($(this));
});

arr2[0].attr('src', arr[0]);
arr2[1].attr('src', arr[1]);
arr2[2].attr('src', arr[2]);
arr2[3].attr('src', arr[3]);
arr2[4].attr('src', arr[4]);
arr2[5].attr('src', arr[5]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just a code you will need ..

```
$('.single-project .et_pb_slide_image img').each(function(i){ // i for image index
    var getsrc = $(this).attr('src');
     $('.single-project .et-pb-controllers a img').eq(i).attr('src', getsrc );
});
```

Comment: I just wasn't nesting my receiving image within my original image's loop when attempting the .eq() code before the code I defaulted to above. Thank you! Works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.each()` to replace the following:

```
arr2[0].attr('src', arr[0]);
arr2[1].attr('src', arr[1]);
arr2[2].attr('src', arr[2]);
arr2[3].attr('src', arr[3]);
arr2[4].attr('src', arr[4]);
arr2[5].attr('src', arr[5]);
```

With:

```
$.each( arr2, function( i ) {
    arr2[i].attr('src', arr[i]);
});
```

**Or better still**, you can take advantage of your last loop to update `arr2` as follows:

```
var arr2 = new Array();
$('.single-project .et-pb-controllers a img').each(function(i) {
     arr2.push( $(this).attr( 'src', arr[i] ) );
});
```

And, if the arrays are not used any place else, you can do away with them per @Mohamed-Yousef's solution.